# Why is my API call in swift throwing two errors?

Tags: swift

The two errors I am getting are:

> "'async' call cannot occur in a global variable initializer"
> and

> "Call can throw, but errors cannot be thrown out of a global variable initializer"

My code is as follows:

```
func getReps() async{
    let apiService = APIService(urlString: (EnvSetup.baseUrl + EnvSetup.apiKey))
    
    await Task{
        let reps: [rep] = try await apiService.getJSON()
        FileManager.endcodeAndSave(objects: reps, fileName: "reps.json")
        print(reps.count)
    }
}
```

I have tried without the async and awaits, adding them in my caller (which is just:

```
async{
    await @Published var Reps: [rep] = getReps()
}
```

This is my first time working with APIs in Swift so it may be a simple file structure issue but I have been working at this for a couple of hours to no avail. I would appreciate any help!

I have tried changing around the async and await commands. However, I keep getting the same errors. The APIService code I am using is Stewart Lynch's and is as follows:

```
import Foundation

public class APIService {
    public let urlString: String
    public init(urlString: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString
    }
    
    public func getJSON<T: Decodable>( dateDecodingStategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
                                       keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys,
                                       completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            fatalError("Error: Invalid URL.")
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                fatalError("Error: Data is corrupt.")
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStategy
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
            
            do {
                let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                completion(decodedData)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    @available(iOS 14, *)
    public func getJSON<T: Decodable>(dateDecodingStategy: JSONDecoder.DateDecodingStrategy = .deferredToDate,
                                      keyDecodingStrategy: JSONDecoder.KeyDecodingStrategy = .useDefaultKeys) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
           fatalError("Error: Invalid URL.")
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        guard let _ = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            fatalError("Error: Data Request error.")
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = dateDecodingStategy
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = keyDecodingStrategy
        guard let decodedData =  try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
           fatalError("Error: Decoding error.")
        }
        return decodedData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions marked with `async` run in an asynchronous context, an extra Task is not needed.

And you have either make the function `throw` or add a `do - catch` block (second error).
If you want to return the data add also a return value.

By the way please name structs and classes with starting uppercase letter

```
func getReps() async throws -> [Rep] {
    let apiService = APIService(urlString: (EnvSetup.baseUrl + EnvSetup.apiKey))
    
    let reps: [Rep] = try await apiService.getJSON()
    FileManager.endcodeAndSave(objects: reps, fileName: "reps.json")
    print(reps.count)
    return reps
}
```

And `async { await @Published var ...` is wrong (first error). On the caller side declare

```
@Published var reps = [Rep]()
```

and implement `init`

```
init() {
    Task {
       reps = (try? await getReps()) ?? []
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed response! I tried implementing your changes, however, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: My code looks like this now and I added your init and changed the await caller as well

Comment: func getReps() async throws -> [Rep]{
     let apiService = APIService(urlString: (EnvSetup.baseUrl + EnvSetup.apiKey))
     
     let reps: [Rep] = try await apiService.getJSON()
     FileManager.endcodeAndSave(objects: reps, fileName: "reps.json")
     print(reps.count)
     return reps
 }

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, but it is exactly as you advised. Do you have any idea why this is not working as well? Thank you again for being so helpful.